# Как передать дату в ActionCreator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, дата

У меня есть поле создание поста через input, где после нажатия на enter или кнопки опубликовать пост вызывается функция ***onAddPost***

```
let onAddPost = () => {
    let text = newPostElement.current.value
    if(text === '' || text === ' ') return
    else{
        let currentDate = new Date()
        props.addPost(currentDate)
    }
}


props.addPost - это ActionCreator который принимает параметр currentDate


export const addPost = (currentDate) => ({ type: ADD_POST, currentDate })
```

Далее он попадет в reduser

```
case ADD_POST: {
        let newPost = {
            id: state.posts.lenght + 1,
            date: action.currentDate,
            message: state.newPostText,
            likeCount: 0,
        }
        return {
            ...state,
            posts: [newPost, ...state.posts],
            newPostText: '',
        }
    }
```

Но при попытке создать такой объект получается ошибка, проблема кроется в этой строчке

```
let currentDate = new Date()
```

При передаче чего либо угодно все работает, подскажите, что делать
Ошибка: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

судя по MDN, размер ваших заголовков слишком велик ([ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/431))

Попробуйте передавать на сервер дату в другом формате, например в формате YYYY-MM-DD:

```
else{
    const cDate = new Date()
    const date = cDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (cDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + cDate.getDate()
    props.addPost(date)
}
```

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо